# What is allele-specific binding?

Tags: genetics, allele, binding-sites

So far all I have found is this:
https://www.biostars.org/p/132527/

My guess is that some alleles, for whatever reason, bind to things like transcription factors 'moreso' (for want of better word - affinity maybe) than others. Or maybe some alleles are more likely to get methylated, for example.

I feel my understanding is very much bare bones. Is anyone able to go through it a  little more comprehensively? Thanks